# Modify an existing gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

When `apply plugin: 'java'` in Gradle, it defines among other tasks `processResources`.
I want to substitute the token/parameter in one of the resource file during `processResources`.
I have the following copy task defined in my `build.gradle`:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens                                                                                                                                                                                         

task initConfig(type: Copy) {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    from("src/resources/assets/js") {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        include 'config.js'                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [host: "${System.env.HOST ?: 'localhost:58080'}" as String])                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    into "$sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir/assets/js"                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

It works fine if I run `gradle -q run initConfig`.
What I want is that this task to be run as part of `processResources` task, I've tried to put the same logic as following:

```
processResources << {
    // same code goes here
}
```

or

```
processResources {
    doLast {
        // same code goes here
    }
}
```

None of them works. So, if run `gradle -q clean processResources` resources are copied, but the token is not replaced.

I don't want to force explicitly run/add `initConfig` when running the build, so ideally `gradle -q build` should do everything necessary.

I believe it is possible, as `build` task itself defines the way to run multiple tasks during its execution. Could not find yet how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`processResources` is (a you can view in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html)) a plain task of type `Copy`. Hence you can configure it exactly in the same way as you're configuring other copy tasks. This will be enough to filter the file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens 

apply plugin: 'java'

processResources {
   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['token.to.replace': 'zombo.com'])
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/32898508) you can find a simple demo.

Comment: Nice, something to try. Yes, I know that processResources extends Copy, just was not sure that you can configure partial copy spec, after looking into https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Sure. Please let me know if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessResources is a task provided by java-plugin, you don't need to add << for modifying it's behaviour.
Simply try :

```
processResources{
  //same Code goes here
}
```

Another workaround could be to add a dependency between processResources and initConfig like this :

```
processResources{
  dependsOn initConfig
}
```

This will execute initConfig before processResources.

Hope this help.

Comment: dependsOn does do the opposite, it first run initConfig, and then processResources, so processResources will override any file copied before. One way to ensure the order is to use mustRunAfter, but in this case you have to provide both tasks for gradle command. The way suggested by Opal looks like a natural solution to me.